# how to add gestures to gesture file

Tags: android, gesture

I save gestures to a gesture File, which works fine. But actually I have the problem, that the gesture file is overwritten all the time I save a new gesture.

How to add gestures to the gesture file, without overwrite all the time?

```
static File mStoreFile = new File ( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory (), "gestures" ); 

if(!mStoreFile.exists ()){
        Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (), "Datei war nicht vorhanden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        File mStoreFile = new File ( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory (), "gestures" );
    }

    GestureOverlayView gestureView = ( GestureOverlayView ) findViewById ( R.id.
            gestureLayout );

    gestureView.addOnGestureListener ( new GesturesProcessor () );
}


private class GesturesProcessor implements GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public void onGestureStarted ( GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event ) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGesture ( GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event ) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGestureEnded ( GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event ) {

        String text;
        gesture = overlay.getGesture ();
        if ( gesture.getLength () < LENGTH_THRESHOLD ) {

            text = "Geste war zu kurz";
            Dialog_Anzeigen2 ( text );
            overlay.clear ( false );

        }

        text = "Geste übernehmen?";
        Dialog_Anzeigen(text);

    }


    @Override
    public void onGestureCancelled ( GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event ) {

    }
```

And this is the part in which the gesture File is saved:

```
 public void confirm() {
        if (gesture != null) {

            Log.d ( "hier", "hier " );
            GestureLibrary store = GestureLibraries.fromFile ( mStoreFile );

            // über den Namen wird festgemacht, zu welcher Applikation die Geste gehören soll
            store.addGesture(name, gesture);
            store.save();

            Log.d ( "hier1", "hier1 " );

            Set<String> entries = store.getGestureEntries();

            Log.d ( "entries1.size ()", "entries1.size() " + entries.size () );



            setResult ( RESULT_OK );



        } else {
            Log.d ( "hier2", "hier2 " );
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Does nobody have got any idea?